# Assign function return value into protected variable in class

Tags: php, laravel

```
use config;
class abc extends xyz{
    protected $adminMail = config('deployment.adminemail');

    public function xyz(){
     ......
    }
}
```

It gives me syntax error for line protected "$adminMail = config('deployment.adminemail'); of (;)"

I know this question is not very logical but please guide where I am getting confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick for you, as far as config() is implemented in the right way.

```
use config;
class abc extends xyz{
    protected $adminMail;

    public function __construct() {
      $this->adminMail = config('deployment.adminemail');
    }

    public function xyz(){
     ......
    }
}
```

Explanation:
You cannot use an expression as a default value, because class variables are initiated before runtime. Means only scalar types like a string or an integer are allowed as default value. The only way to archive this ist within the constructor.

Comment: yes it did but can you explain why it is so why didnt it work without constructor

Comment: I have edited my answer and added an explanation